# What is the difference between Software Project Management Process and Software Development Process?

Tags: project-management, development-process, terminology

What is the difference between Software Project Management Process, and Software Development Process, or Software Life Cycle?

Comment: Please add some details as to what your preconceived notions of the terms in question are. It's rather hard to understand what you are trying to differentiate between if we don't have your perceptions of them.

Comment: The management process is the management of the development process :) - to ensure development runs smoothly, the management removes the hurdles (it may also create some, but that's an another story :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Software Life Cycle is any process model that has specification, development, validation and maintenance phases and these can repeat in cycles so it's sort of the structure of the development processes:

[image: this]

Software project management considers the practical limits, risks and deadlines and forms a complete plan for the entire project and the maintenance of its progress.

see Wikipedia for more details about [Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process) and [Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_project_management)